# integration uairship?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am integrating urban airship in my app i had following all the steps in given link
(https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3A+iOS%3A+Push) but the problem here is i am getting an error that AirshipConfig.plist  file is not found,can some one help me 
thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is create a .plist file with that name, but here is my [AirshipConfig.plist](http://cl.ly/I3BR) file. You just have to fill in your application key and secret.

Answer (score 0):

There should already be a sample file AirshipConfig.plist as part of the download.  However you need to rename the file from AirshipConfig.plist.sample to AirshipConfig.plist and edit the contents (eg, add in application key and secret)